# Can I use a three wire cable to feed a whirlpool tub?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci, tub

If I'm required to add 2 dedicated GFCI circuits for a whirlpool tub and inline heater, can I run 3 wire cable (red,black,white,ground) or do I need 2-2 wire cables?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the circuits are 120V you can run a 3-waire cable. The only caveat is that you would then need to use a two-pole GFI breaker to protect the circuits.

With two 2-wire circuits and single-pole GFI breaker (or devices) you can isolate the circuit for troubleshooting and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this with our Kitchen requiring two GFCI Circuits, we were using GFCI Breakers vs Outlets.  The Neutral needs to be dedicated to the GFcI device so it can detect the fault.  We ended up running two 12/2 circuits instead of the 12/3.

Comment: Or you can use a double-pole GFI breaker with a shared neutral.